# Sorting by nested eager loaded relationships (with pagination)?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, join, laravel-5.1

I am currently developing a system to filter and display data that is used via Eloquent and saved to the database in the following way:

```
Catalog -(1)---(n)-> Product -(1)---(n)-> Group -(n)---(n)-> Part
                     Product -(n)---(n)-> Provider
```

I'm eager loading these models completely and then display their attributes in my view as a table, the columns I base on user settings. Now I'm trying to add a way to order (and search through) these columns, but I can't seem to figure out any way to be able to order the **whole** result (`Catalog` is ultimately the 'master' collection) by any nested attributes.

For parts and providers (n:n relationships) I only need to be able to order the result by either the first or the last one's attributes.

Can anyone help me out here? I tried joins, but I can't figure out how to join both the first element and the last element for those two models and somehow distinguish them.

Comment: If you are displaying results in the table, it will probably be much easier to just add the datatables plugin which will take care of all the sorting for you from the client side.

Comment: @heiko, unfortunately, I am having the same problem and this is not possible(as far as I have been looking and researching for)

Comment: Thanks for the datatables tip! I actually tried using them before, but I failed at the serverside processing... totally forgot to try out local processing. Of course this increases the initial page load time, but it's better than nothing.

Comment: And @Ponce - my research suggests the same. My SQL query knowledge is limited though, so I'll keep this question open in case anyone figures out a more optimized way. :)

Comment: @HeikoRothe I am stuck there actually and re-considering joins instead of depending fully on eager loading. cheers